# Magento 2 installation issue

Tags: php, magento

I have successfully installed Magento 2 on the xampp server but I'm having an issue of loading the admin page as it is giving me a 404. Also, when loading its homepage the default theme,it doesn't apply and instead gives me the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1491913172/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:7777/Magento/pub/static/version1491913172/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/jstree/themes/default/style.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
mixins.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
require.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
magento-icon.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
mixins.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
requirejs-config.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at requirejs-config.js:66
    at requirejs-config.js:71
    at requirejs-config.js:423
127.0.0.1/:39 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:39
127.0.0.1/:87 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:87
127.0.0.1/:298 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:298
127.0.0.1/:430 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:430
127.0.0.1/:475 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:475
127.0.0.1/:533 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:533
127.0.0.1/:556 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:556
127.0.0.1/:579 Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function
    at 127.0.0.1/:579
opensans-400.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
admin-icons.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-600.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-700.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-400.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
admin-icons.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-600.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-700.woff Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-400.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
admin-icons.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-600.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
opensans-700.ttf Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems permission issue. it's common in magento2.

Please try this solution.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93892

after making above changes please execute below command.

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Please try this and let me know if you need any other help. or you can contact me on my skype : mayur.jadeja8

Thanks

Comment: Your Welcome Bnabil. :)

Comment: I tried this, as I am too getting same problem, admin page keeps loading with a loader. However i get error, and this error is only removed if i chmod 777 or g+w/g+ws to file and directories. `Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/user/var/page_cache" is not writable in ......`, so the problem persists